# Как декомпилировать .exe в .py?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, декомпиляция

В общем, я писал небольшой скрипт для на python. Заказчик потребовал, чтобы был готовый exe, поэтому пришлось использовать Pyinstaller (с py2exe у меня выдавало ошибку). Проект выполнен и я решил переустановить винду.
Но потом заказчик попросил переписать скрипт. Исходники я конечно же не забэкапил т.к. думал что к этому проекту уже не вернусь. В итоге, что у меня есть: exe скомпилированный с помощью pyinstaller и исходники старой версии проекта, которые остались на флешке.

Подскажите, можно ли их как-нибудь декомпилировать в .py или мб какое-нибудь другое решение (писать заново - не вариант).

Comment: Есть такое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303122/how-to-decompile-files-from-pyinstaller-pyz-file и есть [Pyinstxtractor](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Pyinstxtractor)

Answer (score 4):

1. Скачиваешь [PyInstaller Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstallerextractor/)
2. Устанавливаешь [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/)
3. Распаковываешь extractor'ом exe'шник
4. Декомпилируешь интересующие pyc-файлы с помощью uncompyle6

Answer (score 3):

хочу предложить для этой задачи небольшой скрипт.
По сути, он объединяет:

1. [PyInstaller Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstallerextractor/)
2. [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/)
3. [unpy2exe](https://pypi.org/project/unpy2exe/)

   Имеет командный интерфейс:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При старте скрипт читает sys.argv и способен принимать не один файл для декомпиляции

#### Важно, при передаче аргументов не нужно передавать команду 'decompile' или '--d'

```
python E:\...\Decompiler.py  E:\...\Decompiler\file1.exe  E:\...\file2.exe  --n  --h
```

Можно указывать папку для декомпиляции, скрипт сам обнаружит .exe или .pyc файлы

```
python E:\...\Decompiler.py  E:\...\Decompiler\DIRNAME\
```

#### Команды можно вводить одной строкой, если указан неверный путь, скрипт запросит новый путь

Для декомпиляции файлов в уже запущенный скрипт введите:

```
--D E:\...\Decompiler\__pycache__
```

#### Регистр не играет никакой роли

Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/topdefaultuser/EXE2PY-Decompiler.git) на страницу программы, общем, надеюсь, кому-то поможет.