# Распаковать файл .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь распаковать файл .exe с помощью:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
zf = ZipFile("/tmp/Test.exe", "r")
zf.extractall("/tmp/WSH")
zf.close()
```

но я получаю такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/manuf/wireshark.py", line 49, in <module>
    zf = ZipFile("/tmp/Test.exe", "r")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне разархивировать файл .exe, мне нужно именно разархивировать.

Мне нужен метод, который извлекёт содержимое упакованного `.exe`. Сейчас я в поисках информации, так как я посмотрел инфо этого файла и нашёл интересную вещь: `Test.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, Nullsoft Installer self-extracting archive`

Comment: Я конечно в винде вообще не шарю, но exe — это не zip-архив. ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, утилита 7 Zip открывает exe :D Пруф: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhXD.png

Comment: @gil9red Да, но я думал, что она открывает его просто зная его структуру... Т.е. не как zip, а подругому... Нет?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, возможно, это вопрос к 7-zip, но странная тогда выходит фича :)

Comment: @gil9red Тоже так думаю, но кто его знает ;) Кстати apk как раз так открывается как zip. Потому что это и есть zip.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, это не винда, это в `Linux`, 
@gil9red, другие `архиваторы`, но дело в том, что обычный файл формата `test.zip` распаковывается без проблем, но и другие форматы эти архиваторы `хавают`, т.е. распаковывают. Также вручную, если `ПКМ` по файлу `.exe` - распаковать - распаковывает, а вот через `Python` ни как, хотя должен тоже хвать всё.

Comment: @AlexRebell "хотя должен тоже хвать всё" - не должен. Архиваторы поддерживают десятки форматов архивов, zipfile поддерживает только формат zip.

Comment: Ну, надо узнать, чем же файл всё-таки запакован. Он вполне может быть и не самораспаковывающийся zip, а что-то совсем другое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как задача стоит для непосредственно исполнения на ОС Linux, я решил проблему следующим образом, точнее не проблему, а её обход:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen(['7z', '-y', 'x', '/tmp/test.exe', '-o/tmp/wsh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = result.communicate()
if len(stderr) == 0:
    print("ggwp")
else:
    print("bg")
```

утилита `7z` практически на всех `Linux` идёт предустановленной.

Comment: где вы ответ нашли ? я точно знаю что инженеров linux на  SO нету

Comment: @MaximLensky, ни где, додумался сам. Ну а информацию по реализации `subprocess` на просторах интернета полным полно.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по беглому просмотру возможностей модуля zipfile он работает только с zip архивами да и ошибка прямо говорит : **BadZipFile: File is not a zip file**.
Важно понять что за ехе файл ты пытаешься распаковать - это ранее скомпилированный питоновский файл?

Бегло прошелся по СОФу и нашел подобный вопрос, не знаю поможет ли, но почитай, может то, что нужно [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877213/Как-декомпилировать-exe-в-py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877213/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-exe-%D0%B2-py)

Comment: `это ранее скомпилированный питоновский файл?`

Нет, это обычный .exe файл, который распаковывается обычным архиватором.
Эту ссылку я читал, вообще не то.

Comment: @AlexRebell обычный архиватор - это какой конкретно архиватор? И что именно вы хотите из обычного exe извлечь?

Comment: @insolor, мне нужен метод, который извлекёт содержимое упакованного `.exe`.
Сейчас я в поисках информации, так как я посмотрел инфо этого файла и нашёл интересную вещь: 

`Test.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, Nullsoft Installer self-extracting archive`

Comment: @AlexRebell, добавьте эту информацию в сам вопрос.