# Как декомпилировать зашифрованный pyinstaller?

Tags: python, декомпиляция

Пытаюсь достать из exe исходный код (python), через pyinstxtractor я достал часть, на остальное выдало много ошибок, вроде этой:

`[!] Error: Failed to decompress xml.sax.expatreader, probably encrypted. Extracting as is.`

---

Comment: Я так понял что это из-за шифрования в pyinstaller. Не могу найти как достать остальные файлы, чтобы достать целый исходный код
файлов .pyc так же нет

Comment: Нашел на github код который объединяет
PyInstaller Extractor

uncompyle6

unpy2exe
-----------
Через него уже появились .pyc файлы

Comment: Попытался достать сходный код `uncompyle6 EXE2PY_Extracted/main.pyc > itog.py`
Выходит новая ошибка.. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xdis.code'`
ема.. но xdis уже установлен..

Comment: Кому интересно - вот ссылка на сам exe файл https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_SnE0x3Dp7yI5wUnOqBLdpIXwal26a3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Вот тут всё, что Вам нужно:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877213/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-exe-%D0%B2-py

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже сказал в комментариях, тут есть вся информация и способы о том, как декомпилировать python-файл:

[Как декомпилировать .exe в .py?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877213/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-exe-%D0%B2-py)

Надеюсь, что ответ Вам помог :)

Comment: Спасибо, но что на новом декомпиляторе, что через uncompyle6 постоянно прилетает ошибка No module named `xdis.code`. Хотя я устанавливал xdis через pip install. Не знаете в чём проблема?

Comment: Тут очень подробно объясняется: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drudNygH9H8

Comment: Да, я в точь в точь сделал. Появляется ошибка `Unsupported Python version, 3.9.0, for decompilation`
Ставил разнве версии python, 3.7, 3.9.7 и сейчас остался 3.9.0 - ошибка не исчезла. Я тут подумал, может это связанно как то с тем, что он программа называется chrome.exe и имеет значок хрома? Может с использованием хрома компилировалась программа, и теперь выдает ошибку..

Comment: Я так понял что это хром приложение, на питоне.. Но мне это мне не дало подсказок, что не так..