# как из exe сделать python если exe файл сделан с помощью pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Есть файл но нужно посмотреть код можно ли обратно превратить exe в py?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как декомпилировать .exe в .py?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877213/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-exe-%d0%b2-py)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `pyinstxtractor.py`:

```
 python pyinstxtractor.py yourFileName.exe
```

Это приведет к извлечению .exe и созданию папки с именем `yourFileName.exe_extracted`.

Внутри `yourFileName.exe_extracted` папки найдите файл без какого-либо расширения.

Отредактируйте его с помощью редактора HxD и из любого `__pycache__` файла, созданного с помощью той же версии Python, скопируйте первую строку и вставьте ее в свой файл.

Сохраните и переименуйте файл с `.pyc` расширением.

Декомпилируйте скомпилированный байт-код (`.pyc`) в `.py` с помощью любого онлайн-инструмента, например https://www.toolnb.com/tools-lang-en/pyc.html